# Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands

Tags: node.js, angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTDuA.png)The same question was already there and I tried all those suggestions.

What I tried is,

1. Uninstalled nodejs and angular.
2. Again installed nodejs and angular globally

While checking the version nodejs and npm is working. But while checking angular it show's the same error again and again

NOTE: I tried almost 10 times to uninstall everything and install everything. But no solution yet.

Comment: Hello! Your problem is that you can't use the angular command line tools like `ng-new`? is that right?

Comment: yes, That's right

Comment: One more thing I already worked with the angular project a year ago and everything was perfect. After a long gap, I came back to work with angular again and I checked the angular version, It shows good except for node(unsupported). So I tried updating the angular then it's all messed up.

Comment: Surely this is the command you are using then `npm install -g @angular/cli`?

Comment: yes. This is the command

Comment: Are you on mac or windows or linux? Hard problem to solve here. it sucks man

Comment: I'm using windows.

Comment: I can't get you. Like I have to email devin at streetmetrics.com ah. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah! just change the at for @

Comment: I have mailed you. Please check it.